# How do I reference a linux directory location in java string?

Tags: java, unix, filesystems

I am getting null pointers with both of these examples:

```
String Dir =   "/mnt/edocs/DEV/SCAN/DONE";
String Dir =   "\\mnt\\edocs\\DEV\\SCAN\\DONE";

File file = new File(Dir);
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: /mnt/edocs/DEV/SCAN/DONE should work. Did you check if this location actually exists?

Comment: The first one should works. My hypothesis is that you forgot the file extension. Are you receiving a FileNotFoundException when instanciating ? Also make sure you have the permission to access that folder.

Comment: It's a CIFS mount on my linux box, it does exist

Comment: what you can do is put these 2 paths in a property file like {pathname}=../path/somepath/etc. then in your java code you can refer these using ${pathname} make sure to load the property file before you access it.

Comment: what is the result of `System.out.print(file.exists());`

Comment: As a test you can try to create a file in the directory of you are trying to read from and see where it ends up creating it.